# EntireRow.Delete performance issue

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete all rows with blanks values. I have about 15,000 rows and no more than 25% are blank. Here is the code I have.

```
Columns("A:A").Select 
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

The first and second lines of code work fine however, when I try to add the third line my spreadsheet times out and I am left with a (Not Responding) message. I think my issue is the amount of rows I am trying to delete at once because the code works when I reduce the amount of content. Can anyone suggest a fix? Why can't excel handle this?

Comment: Which Excel version are you using? Also can you replace this line `Selection.EntireRow.Delete` with `Debug.Print Selection.Address` and then run the code. Can you paste here what do you get?

Comment: what does debug.printselection.address do? I am using Excel 2007

Comment: It will show you in the immediate window the address of the range that consists of those blank cells. You can also use `Msgbox Selection.Address`

Comment: What is the purpose of needing to remove the blanks? Maybe you can look for a solution from a different angle? Can you just filter them out of view?

Answer (score 3):

The reason this takes so long is the large number of *non-contiguous* ranges in `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`

A better way is to sort the data before the delete, so only one *contiguous* range is deleted

You can then restore the original sort order after the delete, something like this:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rSortCol As Range
    Dim rDataCol As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim BlockSize As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim TempCol As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = sh.UsedRange
    With rng

        ' Add a temporary column to hold a index to restore original sort
        TempCol = .Column + .Columns.Count
        Set rSortCol = .Columns(TempCol)
        rSortCol.Cells(1, 1) = 1
        rSortCol.Cells(1, 1).AutoFill rSortCol, xlFillSeries
        Set rng = rng.Resize(, rng.Columns.Count + 1)
        
        Set rDataCol = rng.Columns(1)

        ' sort on data column, so blanks get grouped together
        With sh.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=rDataCol, _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange rng
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        
        ' delete blanks (allow for possibility there are no blanks)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = rDataCol.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            ' no blank cells
            Err.Clear
        Else
            rng.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' Restore original sort order
        With sh.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=rSortCol, _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange rng
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    
    End With

    ' Delete temp column
    sh.Columns(TempCol).EntireColumn.Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

My testing (on ~15000 rows, every 4th row blank) reduced time from ~20s to ~150ms

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running on ALL rows on the spreadsheet; it would be quicker to run it on the used rows.

Something like this:

```
Range("A1", Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Address).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Or, could you just sort the data range - that'd group all the blanks together...

Comment: The time it takes is still too long. Even manually selecting blanks and delete 1,000 rows at a time takes forever.

Comment: Actually its not using the whole sheet (at least in Excel 2010) - `SpecialCells` only return from the used range